# Eclipse e4: add commands to context menu

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

I defined several commands in my Application Model, say like openCommand, saveCommand. And I can add them to the menu bar or tool bar easily. Now I want them to also appear in the context menu of the edit part, how can this be done?

To be short, I want a menu item in main menu, a tool bar item in tool bar and another menu item in context menu. All these three items have the same function and thus should be mapped to the same command. I can do the first two but have no idea about the third.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You define the context menu for a Part in the Menu section of the Part Descriptor in the application model. Add a 'Popup Menu' and give it a unique id. Add menu items to the popup menu in the normal way.

Tell Eclipse the menu is the context menu for a control using the `EMenuService`:

```java
@Inject
private EMenuService menuService;

...

menuService.registerContextMenu(control, "menu id");
```

Comment: @greg449 I cannot find EMenuService class, do I need to add some plug-in here? Thanks!

Comment: EMenuService is from org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt bundle, physically it is org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_[version].jar

Comment: For Eclipse 4.4 EMenuService moves to the org.eclipse.e4.ui.services package in the org.eclipse.e4.ui.services plugin. For 4.3 and earlier it is in org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt